# Webform menu access control

Tags: routes, webforms

I'm using Drupal 7 with Webform and Content Access contrib modules.

I wrote a little snippet that displays all items for a given menu, and greys out the ones that the user doesn't have access to, while the accessible ones are links.

I get the access control information with

```
menu_link_load(menu_load_links(menu_my_menu)[mlid])[access]
```

...if that helps at all. It returns 1 if access should be granted, and NULL if not.

The problem I'm encountering is that, while this code works swimmingly for normal nodes, webforms seem to return a 1 for access even when the logged-in user does not have permission to submit that form. So the link shows up, and then it takes the user to a page that says "You do not have permission to view this form."

What function do I call to find out whether a webform of a certain path (or title or whatever I can find out from menu_link_load) should be visible to the user?

Comment: I've also added a [bug report in the Webform issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1572580#comment-5985928).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to resolve this is to use [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and specify the View permission for a Webform, rather than Webform's "can submit" permission.  In other words, **by using the Content Access module's View Permission** instead of the Webform "can submit" permission, **you can utilize the code you're currently using**.  To do this you'll have to set a separate View permission for each Webform.

The problem originates from Webform's permissions conflict with Drupal core: Drupal's standard View permission may be true, but the Webform "You can submit this form" permission can be false, which gives a different Access Denied message from above.

I attempted to dig up an alternate solution, creating some custom code to derive the access for Webform menu items, but it really was looking horrendous.  Webform does not have a function that returns "You can submit this webform" access, and trying to efficiently determine if a menu item is a webform was looking pretty foul.

Comment: Works brilliantly. I hadn't realized that I hadn't enabled per-node access control on webforms, and that I was only using the built-in "can submit" permissions. You've saved whatever hair I haven't already pulled out in frustration.